# Add arrays of different lengths

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
int [] array1 = {2, 4, 5};
int [] array2 = {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 1};
```

I want add these two arrays, I want this result:

```
int [] result = {3, 8, 11, 5, 2, 1};
```

But, what is the length of the array result?, array1.length or array2.length?

But, I have a dude, if I can amplied the first array so:

```
int [] array1 = {2, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0};
```

Sorry by my bad English, thank you very much!

Comment: *"But, what is the length of the array result?"* Um... [`Math.max(array1.length, array2.length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-)? `array1.length < array2.length ? array2.length : array1.length`?

Comment: Yes, but, later when I can add, exists the error: ArrayOutBoundsOfException because the array1 is more little than the one I want resolve this.

Comment: Well yes. You use a guard so you don't try to access beyond the end of the shorter array.

Comment: You're doing something here, but you're not explaining *what that is*. Are you simply adding values in same array positions together? If so you already know what the length is going to be. Are you doing something else (it looks like you're adding values on index but looks can be deceiving)? Then explain *what you're doing* and show the code you're using to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] addArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
  int[] result;
  int[] smallPtr;

  if (a1.length <= a2.length){
    result = Arrays.copyOf(a2);
    smallPtr = a1;
  } else {
    result = Arrays.copyOf(a1);
    smallPtr = a2;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < smallPtr.length; i++) {
    result[i] += smallPtr[i];
  }

  return result;  
}
```

The `for` loop is pretty standard code to just add elements of the arrays one by one. The "magic" is happening in the `if/else` statement above along with `result` and `smallPtr`;

`result` is self explanatory enough, namely the result array which will be returned to the client. `smallPtr` is a "pointer" to the smaller of the two arrays. The `if/else` block then simply tries to determine which array is the smallest one and sets that equal to `smallPtr` whilst making a copy of the larger array. Then we just simply iterate through the small array and add those elements to the copy of the large array, giving us the answer.

There are multiple ways to approach this problem. One way is to just have tons of `if` statements inside a for `loop` which just check the boundary conditions of the arrays to prevent `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s. This solution however tries to make the code terse (and hopefully easier to read and understand) by just having one `if/else` block.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two arrays:
>
> int [] array1 = {2, 4, 5}; int [] array2 = {1, 4, 6, 5, 2, 1};
>
> I want add these two arrays, I want this result:
>
> int [] result = {3, 8, 11, 5, 2, 1};

The main challenges here are:

- how to determine the size of the result array
- how to handle asymmetric arrays

The first challenge is easily solved as a maximum of the two array lengths.  Solving the second challenge simply requires handling the case when an element in one array has no partner in the other.  Here is a solution:

```
public int[] addArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int maxLength = (array1.length > array2.length) ? array1.length : array2.length;
    int index = 0;
    int[] sums = new int[maxLength];


    while (index < maxLength) {
       sums[index]  = (index < array1.length) ? array1[index] : 0;
       sums[index] += (index < array2.length) ? array2[index] : 0;
       index++;
    }
    return sums;
}
```

Note how the use of the *ternary operator* renders this code more readable than would be the case with block if-then statements.